# How to keep the value of dropdown list after rest call for select tag with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to keep the value the user selected when changing a dropdown list value for displaying items in a page based on that value. With that value, I'm calling a rest service to retrieve that number of records but it is only doing once, if I change again is not triggering the call and not updating the value even in the first time is not assigning the value on the dropdown. Anyone has faced this same issue, what is the correct form to use change event in jQuery?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dpItemsU').change(changeItemsPerPage);
});

function changeItemsPerPage() {
    var newItems = $('#dpItemsU').val();
    searchResultsREST(myQuery, "U", newItems, 0);
    $('#dpItemsU').val(newItems);
}

<select id="dpItemsU">
  <option value="">Select</option>                                      
  <option value="3">3</option>                                      
  <option value="10">10</option>                                        
  <option value="20">20</option>                                        
  <option value="30">30</option>                                        
  <option value="40">40</option>                                        
  <option value="50">50</option>                                    
</select> items per page
```

Comment: You are always resetting the same value! Is `searchResultsREST` asynchronous?

Comment: Also you are not saving the selected value anywhere. if you want to refresh the same list always you need to define a temp var and save the selected option there

Comment: I see the ajax as follows: $.ajax({
     url: searchURL,
     method: "GET",
     headers: {
      "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
     },
     contentType: "application/json; odata=verbose",
     success: function(data) {
      SearchResultsOnSuccess(data, _region, _startRow, _rowLimit);
     },
     error: function(error) {
      $('#related-content-results').html(JSON.stringify(error));
     }
    });
I don't see the async property so I guess is not asynchronous, am I correect?

Comment: newItems should have the selected value when changing the dropdown

Comment: Even if I remove the ajax call, it works only once, it updates the value in dropdown only once.